# Cut off the field from JSON string

Tags: json, scala

I have a JSON string like this:

```
{"id":"111","name":"abc","ids":["740"],"data":"abc"}
```

I want to cut off the field `"ids"`, however I don't know apriori the values like `["740"]`. So, it might be e.g. `["888,222"]` or whatever. The goal is to get the json string without the field `"ids"`.

How to do it?  Should I use `JackMapper`?

**EDIT:**

I tried to use `JackMapper` as `JacksMapper.readValue[Map[String, String]]`(jsonString)`to get only fields that I need. But the problem is that`"ids":["740"]` throws the parsing error because it's an array. So, I decided to cut off this field before parsing, though it's an ugly solution and ideally I just want to parse the json string into Map.

Comment: What programming language are you working with?

Comment: @BrankVictoria: scala, as it's indicated in the tags

Comment: @cchantep: I tried to use `JackMapper` as `JacksMapper.readValue[Map[String, String]](jsonString)` and then get only fields that I need. But the problem is that `"ids":["740"]` throws parsing error. So, I decided to cut off this field before parsing, though it's an ugly solution and ideally I just want to parse the json string into Map.

Comment: I don't know about JacksMapper but you can try to read your value as `Map[String, JsonValue]` as such, you can get rid of the `ids` without getting parsing error

Comment: @LouisF. This is indeed a good idea. Could you please show it in the answer?

Comment: I am afraid that I cannot give a comprehensive answer as I don't have any knowledge on JackMapper nor in the Json library you are using. But I think you got the big picture. Try to parse your json as a map of string - json and get rid of the desired key and parse it back to string

Comment: @duckertito Give a complete code if you want advices about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what JackMapper is, but if other libraries are allowed, my personal favourites would be:

[Play-JSON](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJson):

```
val jsonString = """{"id":"111","name":"abc","ids":["740"],"data":"abc"}"""
val json = Json.parse(jsonString).as[JsObject]
val newJson = json - "ids"
```

[Circe:](https://github.com/circe/circe)

```
import io.circe.parser._

val jsonString = """{"id":"111","name":"abc","ids":["740"],"data":"abc"}"""
val json = parse(jsonString).right.get.asObject.get // not handling errors
val newJson = json.remove("ids")
```

Note that this is the minimal example to get you going which doesn't handle bad input etc.

Comment: In case of the first solution (Play-JSON), how to convert `newJson` to `Map[String,String]`?

Comment: I did it as follows: `newJson.fields.toMap.map(v => (v._1,v._2.toString))`

Comment: `newJson.value.mapValues(_.toString())`

Comment: I forgot to say that I am limited to Java 1.7 and Scala 2.10. I see that Circe parser exists only for Scala 2.11 (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.circe/circe-parser_2.11/0.6.1), and Play-JSON requires Java 8.

Comment: Play JSON has been around for Java 7 too. It was Play 2.4. that switched to Java 8 (due to the fact that Java 7 was declared deprecated and reached its end of life in April 2015). Just make sure to get the right dependency. You can get 2.3.4 with `libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-json" % "2.3.4"`. Of course, API may be different, but your use case is surely supported. Here's the [link](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaJson) to docs.